# How to count the distinct values across a column in pandas

Tags: pandas

i have a dataframe like:

```
Company Date        Country
ABC     2017-09-17   USA
BCD     2017-09-16   USA
ABC     2017-09-17   USA
BCD     2017-09-16   USA
BCD     2017-09-16   USA
ABC     2017-09-19   USA
```

I want to get a resultant df as :

```
Company  No: of distinct Days
ABC      2
BCD      1
```

How do i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

`df[['Company', 'Date']].drop_duplicates()['Company'].value_counts()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nunique`  method of the groupby objects:

```
df.groupby('Company')['Date'].nunique()
Out: 
Company
ABC    2
BCD    1
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```